# SWT: MenuItem cannot setImage in Linux

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp

Developing an application using SWT to work in both Linux and Windows.

I created a Menu with a single MenuItem that has an image.  **The image in the menuItem shows on windows but not on linux**.  Is this expected behavior for Linux?  Any workarounds?

```
Menu menu = new Menu(shell, SWT.POP_UP);
MenuItem item = new MenuItem(menu, SWT.PUSH);
item.setImage((ResourceManager.getPluginImage(MyPlugin.PLUGIN_ID, "icons/myimage.gif")));
item.setText("TEXT");
```

Comment: By the way, I'm using Fedora if it makes a difference.

Comment: which eclipse are you using? I mean the one available at the fedora repository or from the eclipse.org site? I faced this issue with my fedora 11 and eclipse downloaded from the fedora.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a GTK problem that can be fixed by tweaking settings - see https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=293720

I run ubuntu (lucid) and fixed this through running gconf-editor from the command line, navigating to desktop->gnome->interface and ticking "menus_have_icons"